# Symfony2 doesn't redirect properly after logout

Tags: symfony

I use Symfony 2.2.11, and the BeSimpleSsoAuth bundle (ref 4ba8ada3) for the SSO-CAS authentication.

When I logout, I'm correctly redirected to the logout page of the SSO. Then the SSO redirects me to the /login_check on my webapp and that finally redirects me to the login page. That's (almost) fine for me. The “almost” comes from the fact that I don't understand why I'm redirected to the login_check, rather than the root given that my `security.yml` file contains:

```
firewalls:
    people:
        pattern: ^/
        switch_user: true
        trusted_sso:
            manager: my_cas
            login_action: false
            logout_action: false
            create_users: false
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /

access_control:
    - { path: ^/owner/*, roles: ROLE_OWNER }
    - { path: ^/user/*, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

I thought the `target` would mean where the logout page should redirect. There is an additional problem: if I happen to log in again from the page I've been redirected to, then I will be directly redirected to `/login_check` which will give the following error:

> Unable to find the controller for path "/login_check". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration?

But if I directly access to the root of my app (let's say `http://localhost/test/web/app_dev.php`), I'm being redirected to:

- SSO login page: `https://sso-cas.myprovider.com/login?service=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftest%2Fweb%2Fapp_dev.php%2Flogin_check`
- then: `http://localhost/test/web/app_dev.php/login_check?ticket=ST-433244-dLDEe4hoShmzdp26f2dU-sso-cas.myprovider.com`
- and finally: `http://localhost/test/web/app_dev.php/owner/`

In that case, I access `/login_check` without any trouble, compared to the other case where I have an error. What is the difference? And, side question, why am I redirected to `/login_check` after logout?

Thanks!